How to make AI Character move towards Actor Object
I have in my scene an AI Character and Actor Object, but the character won't move no matter what I've tried. You can see the current code with debug statements. I'm not sure what I'm missing because I'm new to this, but I hope it's simple.



Follow this link below, if that helps your case -
https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=ue5+patrol+ai

This is currently a link-only answer. These are prone to rot if the resource they're linking to moves, goes offline, or is unreachable from a reader's country. Please edit your answer to explain how to use the information you found to solve the problem, so that it can be understood even without clicking the link. Links are great for attribution or for further details, but an answer should always be able to stand on its own without them. Answers that don't are subject to deletion.
